# On Severi's definition of the complementary correspondence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, curves-and-surfaces, definitions

In Weil's short note entitled "*On the Riemann hypothesis in function-fields*"
he mentions the notion of the **complementary correspondence** associated to a given correspondence $T:C\rightarrow C$ where $C$ is an algebraic curve. He gives a reference to one of Severi's papers for the definition, which I did not bother to look at since I probably won't be able to understand the definition.

**Q1**: So what is the definition of the complementary correspondence of $T$ in modern language?

**Q2**: Is there a good modern reference where the theory of correspondences is developed from scratch and is presented in a geometrical and intuitive way (so that it conveys the intuition of the Italian's school without distorting it too much) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a correspondence $T \subset C \times C$ one defines an endomorphism of the Jacobian of $C$ by letting $T(P)$ be the divisor on $C$ cut out in $T$ by $\{P\}\times C$, extending by linearity and then taking linear equivalence classes. So the ring of endomorphisms is a quotient of the ring of correspondences. I think the complementary correspondence is a good representative of the equivalence class of the endomorphism $-T$ obtained by representing elements of the Jacobian as $\sum_{i=1}^g P_i - gP_0$, for a fixed $P_0$.

Modern books seem to focus on endomorphisms instead of correspondences (e.g. Mumford). There is a little bit of correspondences in Griffiths-Harris the way you want but it doesn't go very far.

Comment: So if we think of $T:C\rightarrow C$ as a multivalued function and $T(P)=\sum_{i} [P_i]$ (formal sum) then are you saying that $(-T)(P)=\sum_{i} [-P_i]$?

Comment: @HugoChapdelaine Yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in no 17 of Igusa's paper "[On the theory of algebraic correspondences...](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1261735488)", J. Math. Soc. Japan 1 (1949), [DOI: 10.2969/jmsj/00120147](https://doi.org/10.2969/jmsj/00120147); it corresponds to Felipe Voloch's guess.

(There are many typos in Igusa's paper, and the Project Euclid scan does not improve them. Better read a hard copy if possible.)